# SQL: how to get more information from a GROUP BY statement

Tags: sql, group-by

Consider the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT 
invoice.customer_name, 
invoice.customer_id, 
invoice.shop_location,
sum(invoice.cost)
FROM invoice
GROUP BY
invoice.customer_name, invoice.customer_id, invoice.shop_location
```

What can be done to the statement to identify which rows would be identical to other rows if it weren't for their `invoice.shop_location` value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this - Removing Invoice.ShopLocation

```
SELECT  
invoice.customer_name,  
invoice.customer_id,  
sum(invoice.cost) 
FROM invoice 
GROUP BY 
invoice.customer_name, invoice.customer_id
```

This gives you all rows which match rest of the fields

Comment: Perhaps my question isn't clear. I want to know which rows exist in the result only because of a different invoice.shop_location

Comment: Add `HAVING count(DISTINCT invoice.shop_location) > 1` to Sachin's query would do exactly that.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select customer_name, Customer_id, count(Shop_location) from
(
    SELECT  
        invoice.customer_name,  
        invoice.customer_id,  
        invoice.shop_location, 
        sum(invoice.cost) 
    FROM invoice 
    GROUP BY 
        invoice.customer_name, 
        invoice.customer_id,
        invoice.shop_location 
 )
 Group by customer_name, Customer_id
 Having    count(Shop_location) > 1
```

The above query will give you the combination of Customername and id who have more than one shop location

*Note : I'm not sure whether this is optimised*

Comment: I want the original query result to have a value in the row to identify this.

Comment: on top of my head, I think you could join this query with your query to get your result...  I will research and post if there is something more elagant...